# How can I validate an nonce passed to another domain and back trough URL?

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I'm creating an Wordpress nonce on an user api login (domain1) and then send this nonce back to the domain (domain2) where the request came from. From domain2 there is another call made to domain1 for retrieving data, again through api, with the nonce created on login. This nonce is used for verifying this action.

Is this the right thing to do, if correct; Why is the result of wp_verify_nonce false?

My code:

```
function login() {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $_GET["username"];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_GET["password"];
    $user = wp_signon($creds, false);

    if (!is_wp_error($user))
    {
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
        $url =  "http://hongarijestek2/view/login.html?nonce=" . $nonce;
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
} 

function get_visitors( $data ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $nonce = $_GET['nonce'];
    if( wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['nonce'], 'wp-rest' ) ) {
        echo "Nonce is ok!";
    } else {
        echo "Nonce is not ok!";
        die();
    }


    $visitors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM cp_visitors_present");

    if ( empty( $visitors ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $visitors;
}
```

Comment: $_GET is an array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters. So can you confirm you actually have the $_GET values when in the get_visitors function?

Comment: Yes I can, is this is even the right way of doing this, what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you explain the logic and separate it via the code samples so we can see how it is meant to flow. Depending on the actions its useful to know that In WordPress, nonces are specific to the user and the action being performed at that time. A nonce is valid for 24 hours and changes every 12.

Comment: Step 1: From domain 2 there is a call send to domain 1 via a login form using the get method.
Step 2: Domain 1 has the login function that will create a nonce if the login is successful bases on the get variables. An redirect with the nonce as an parameter will go to domain 2. 
Step 3: From domain 2 there is another call to domain 1 with the nonce as a parameter. This nonce will be used for verifying the logged in user in the get_visitors function. 

Is it possible to switch between domains en use the nonce in the way that I do?

Comment: Nonces are specific to the domain they are created on, which uses the SALTS in WP-Config. So if you are trying to authenticate a nonce created on domain 2 over at domain 1 it won't work. Also, you probably want to use $_POST as it is a little more secure than GET.

Comment: GET was used for testing only, thank you for your answer!